# How to get the Response from Web-to-lead Form after returning to the given URL in salesforce

Tags: php

**Here is the Form Code i am using :**

```
<form name="download_frm" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

            <input type=hidden name="oid" value="***********">
            <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://----/">
            <!--<input type="hidden" name="debug" value="1"> -->
            <p><input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50" class=""  placeholder="Name"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" value="" name="mail" id="mail" maxlength="50" class="" placeholder="E-mail"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" value="" name="org_name" id="org_name" maxlength="50" class="" placeholder="Organization Name"/></p>
            <p>
            <select name="org_typ" id="org_typ" >
                <option selected="selected">Organization Type</option>
                {if isset($orgtypes)}
                    {foreach $orgtypes as $array}
                        <option value="">{$array->Dev_Type}</option>
                    {/foreach}
                {/if}
            </select>
            </p>
            <p><input type="number" value="" name="phnum" id="phnum" maxlength="50" class="" placeholder="Phone Number(Optional)"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" value="" name="cntry" id="cntry" maxlength="50" class="" placeholder="Country (Optional)"/></p>

            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit form" /></p>
    </form>
```

After submitting the form,it is returning to the given returnURL.But i want to get the information whether the form data is stored successfully or not.

Please Advise me..
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Salesforce Web to Lead code is designed to work with all web servers / web sites / pages, by design it doesn't retrieve that information in regular usage. Whether the submission is successful, or fails, it will simply redirect the visitor to the page specified in retURL.

This behavior might be frustrating if you want information back, but it does allow the web-to-lead to be used practically anywhere, which is the point.

You can, in testing, enable debugging mode. See the original HTML produced by the Salesforce Web to Lead code generator. This will enable an intermediary page that will show you what is being submitted. However, you would not want to use this on a production site, as all of your customers would see this intermediary page.

If you're worried about rejected submissions, that is rare, and in any case Salesforce will send you an email with the submitted form values and why it failed. It will usually fail because of validation rules (to get around this, use Page Layout rules rather than validation rules if you want to require a field to be populated).

You still have a couple options to accomplish what you are trying to do.

One is simply to check Salesforce Leads for submissions - but I presume this information need to be processed, not just viewed by a human.

In that case, the rest of your options require you to do something more than use the standard web to lead code if you want your website to know about the form submission.

Presuming you're using a common CMS you can use plugins for Wordpress ([Gravity Forms Salesforce Add-On](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/) or [Wordpress to Lead](https://wordpress.org/plugins/salesforce-wordpress-to-lead/)) or Drupal's Webforms with the Salesforce add-on.

Or, alternatively, you can re-write the form as a PHP file (or a similar language) that passes the information to Salesforce via CURL - and does any other number of things at the same time using PHP, like passing it to another database. There's a lot on the internet - just google 'salesforce web to lead php curl'

All of the above options work for all versions of Salesforce. If you have Enterprise and higher, or Professional with the API, you can also pass the information to Salesforce via the API. This will allow you to bring back information such as the Lead ID - or pass the information to other objects, de-dupe, upsert, etc. Keep in mind this level of coding is both more complex and will require authentication into Salesforce, so only follow this option if the added functionality is worth the additional overhead.